# pyarrow ORC extension install

Tags: python, pyarrow, orc, apache-arrow

I am trying to use pyarrow with orc but i don't find how to build it with orc extension, anyone knows how to ?

I am on Windows 10

```py
File ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\owlna-0.0.1-py3.9.egg\owlna\table.py:9, in <module>
      7 import pyarrow.csv as pcsv
      8 from pyarrow import Schema, RecordBatch, schema, RecordBatchReader
----> 9 from pyarrow.dataset import FileFormat, CsvFileFormat, ParquetFileFormat, write_dataset, \
     10     partitioning as partitioning_builder, Partitioning, OrcFileFormat
     11 from pyarrow.fs import S3FileSystem
     13 from .config import DEFAULT_SAFE_MODE

File ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\dataset.py:91, in __getattr__(name)
     89 def __getattr__(name):
     90     if name == "OrcFileFormat" and not _orc_available:
---> 91         raise ImportError(_orc_msg)
     93     if name == "ParquetFileFormat" and not _parquet_available:
     94         raise ImportError(_parquet_msg)

ImportError: The pyarrow installation is not built with support for the ORC file format.
```

Comment: How did you install pyarrow? Using pip or conda? And which version do you have installed?

Comment: I tried with both pip or conda, pyarrow==10.0.0

Comment: Ah, it seems that ORC is included in wheels for Linux/Mac, but not for Windows. That explains why you get this error. I opened a JIRA for supporting this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-18329